# To be gold is to be good

Tags: riddle

A who-am-I riddle

> It can be said:
> To be gold is to be good;
> To be stone is to be nothing;
> To be glass is to be fragile;
> To be cold is to be cruel;

Who/what am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are a

> Heart

To be gold is to be good

> Heart of Gold = describes someone who is good-natured and generous.

To be stone is to be nothing

> Heart of Stone = describes a heart which is unfeeling.

To be glass is to be fragile

> Heart of Glass = describes someone that is easily heart-broken.

To be cold is to be cruel

> Cold Hearted = describes someone lacking affection or warmth.

Comment: Great fast work. Sorry, can only accept answer in 6 minutes. ;-)